# Scripting Language Design?

Tags: language-agnostic, scripting, language-design

If I were to go to a dev. company and say "Please build me 'this' scripting language", are there any specific documents, and what types of documents that I should create, so they know exactly what I am wanting?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: First, figure out what's wrong with the dozen or so scripting languages that already exist.

Comment: First you have to know exactly what you want. Then follow Ignacio's advice.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave Swersky says, there are lots and lots of very well developed scripting languages already out there. Lua, for example, is very simple yet surprisingly powerful and has tiny yet efficient implementations.

But if you really, really want a scripting language custom built for you, then the nicest thing you could do for the implementor would be to provide him with a description of the language in [Backus-Naur form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form). Ideally, that will allow them to create a scanner and parser for your language with very little effort. In addition, you will need to define your language's data types and how the map to the hardware's data types, and you will need to specify which library or built-in functions you want to provide, and how those will have effects in the outside world. The [Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/) is concise yet complete and defines that language and its library well. You'll want to come up with something comparable, or make do with a hand-waving simplification and hope your implementors invest their own brain power in filling the gaps left by your description.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could offer some detail on *why* you would want to go to the time and expense to develop your own scripting language when there are at least three or four excellent options out there for free.  If you have a targeted need for a language that does something specific, read up on Domain Specific Languages.

Comment: This does not answer the question.